# Photoshop/JavaScript app.activeDocument.layers.length very slow

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I wrote a script, that finds all groups(LayerSets) that don´t contain any other group.
It works fine on small files, but is really slow on bigger ones.
After some testing I found out, that the function "layers.length" takes a lot of time to execute.

Running only this one line of code, takes a few seconds in a file with 200 layers:
`app.activeDocument.layers.length`

Because I use a recursive approach, I need to run it for every group.

Any ideas how I can optimise this code or any other way to get all groups in a document?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't store the length of layers before you start recursion? Will the layers change during recursion?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can´t store the length, because i don´t know how many subfolders are in each folder. That´s why i choose the recursion.

Comment: Without seeing your code, have you looked [here](https://www.ps-scripts.com/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=24476&p=152815&hilit=slow#p152815)?